# Computing a specific coefficient in a quotient of polynomials

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, polynomials

## Context

After ["Computing a specific coefficient in a product of polynomials"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/198779/75323), asking you to compute a specific coefficient of polynomial multiplication, I wish to create a "mirror" challenge, asking you to compute a specific coefficient from polynomial division.

## Polynomial division

Let us establish an analogy with integer division. If you have two integers `a` and `b`, then there is a unique way of writing `a = qb + r`, with `q, r` integers and `0 <= r < b`.

Let `p(x), a(x)` be two polynomials. Then there is a unique way of writing `a(x) = q(x)p(x) + r(x)`, where `q(x), r(x)` are two polynomials and the degree of `r(x)` is strictly less than the degree of `p(x)`.

## Algorithm

Polynomial division can be performed through an iterative algorithm:

1. Initialize the quotient at `q(x) = 0`
2. While the degree of `a(x)` is at least as big as the degree of `p(x)`:

   - let `n = degree(a) - degree(p)`, let `A` be the coefficient of the term of highest degree in `a(x)` and `P` be the coefficient of highest degree in `p(x)`.
   - do `q(x) = q(x) + (A/P)x^n`
   - update `a(x) = a(x) - p(x)(A/P)x^n`
3. `q(x)` is the quotient and what is left at `a(x)` is the remainder, which for our case will always be `0`.

## Task

Given two polynomials `a(x)`, `p(x)` such that there exists `q(x)` satisfying `a(x) = p(x)q(x)` (with all three polynomials having integer coefficients), find the coefficient of `q(x)` of degree `k`.

(Yes, we are assuming the remainder is `0`)

## Input

Two polynomials (with integer coefficients) and an integer.

Each input polynomial can be in any sensible format. A few suggestions come to mind:

- A string, like `"1 + 3x + 5x^2"`
- A list of coefficients where index encodes exponent, like `[1, 3, 5]`
- A list of `(coefficient, exponent)` pairs, like `[(1, 0), (3, 1), (5, 2)]`

An input format must be sensible AND completely unambiguous over the input space.

The integer `k` is a non-negative integer. You may take it in any of the usual ways. You can assume `k` is less than or equal to the differences of the degrees of `a(x)` and `p(x)`, i.e. `k <= deg(a) - deg(p)` and you can assume `deg(a) >= deg(p)`.

## Output

The **integer** corresponding to the coefficient of `x^k` in the polynomial `q(x)` that satisfies the equality `a(x) = q(x)p(x)`.

## Test cases

The input order for the test cases is `a(x)`, `p(x)`, integer `k`.

```
[12], [4], 0 -> 3
[0, 0, 6], [0, 3], 0 -> 0
[0, 0, 6], [0, 3], 1 -> 2
[0, 70, 70, 17, 70, 61, 6], [0, 10, 10, 1], 0 -> 7
[0, 70, 70, 17, 70, 61, 6], [0, 10, 10, 1], 1 -> 0
[0, 70, 70, 17, 70, 61, 6], [0, 10, 10, 1], 2 -> 1
[0, 70, 70, 17, 70, 61, 6], [0, 10, 10, 1], 3 -> 6
[0, -50, 20, -35, -173, -80, 2, -9, -10, -1], [0, 10, 10, 1], 0 -> -5
[0, -50, 20, -35, -173, -80, 2, -9, -10, -1], [0, 10, 10, 1], 1 -> 7
[0, -50, 20, -35, -173, -80, 2, -9, -10, -1], [0, 10, 10, 1], 2 -> -10
[0, -50, 20, -35, -173, -80, 2, -9, -10, -1], [0, 10, 10, 1], 3 -> -8
[0, -50, 20, -35, -173, -80, 2, -9, -10, -1], [0, 10, 10, 1], 4 -> 1
[0, -50, 20, -35, -173, -80, 2, -9, -10, -1], [0, 10, 10, 1], 5 -> 0
[0, -50, 20, -35, -173, -80, 2, -9, -10, -1], [0, 10, 10, 1], 6 -> -1
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it... And happy golfing!

(This is **not** part of the [RGS Golfing Showdown](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18545/75323))

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/842/75323)

Comment: The 4,5,6 examples are wrong: q(x)=7 + x^2 + 6 x^3 so coefficients {0,1,2,3} = {7,0,1,6}

Comment: Note to self: never do test cases by hand and late at night again

Comment: @J42161217 thanks, I had skipped the test case with only `x` and counted wrong :p fixed!

Comment: Also in first test case 15/4 = 15/4 not 3

Comment: @J42161217 where? :P

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_synthetic_division#Python

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
Y-PiQ)
```

The inputs contain the coefficients in order of decreasing powers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D9SNyAzUPO/S8j/aDMFM0MFcwMFQ3MQCUQGsVzRhgqGBiAEZBsAAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##lY/BCgIxDETv/Yq5eghk0m2rdz9AwctSFvQo6M3/ry3iRUQ3EIYMmReS@@Vxa@c2y@F63LT9qVXaEuq0BA01Q6HdxaGfnsNnoihYhpbXkKCOeiO/Iyu22P9IDFUI6UZ2MMi2NywREhOs9@nbaU6CbsLchP@PyU0kN5Gf)

#### Explanation

> [(De)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67650/36398)[convolution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104655/natural-pi-2-river#comment254339_104685) [is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198788/36398) [the](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105820/36398) [key](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89194/36398) [to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67650/36398) [success](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112819/36398)

```
     % Implicit inputs: two numerical vectors
Y-   % Deconvolution 
P    % Flip
i    % Input: integer
Q    % Add 1
)    % Get the entry at that position
     % Implicit display
```

Comment: Really short answer! Didn't know of that "deconvolution" operation

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
Coefficient[Factor[#/#2],x,#3]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rdA9C4MwEAbg3V9RFLokoflQo0NBKHTuLgZE1DqoIBnu36eJUGlLO1SyhNxd3ickY63v7VjroalNfzaXue26oRnaSZfXutHzUkaniFcYcCSqo7ktw6QPRV8yjmNMq2BtFGEYbJMUFMcCtuFrj/0IpChloBIkKagYMQlKrHvuVuwqtlZ2/XT/ibL9Ub4/Kr49mpKEAuLuEBGJDRAmhbVIRp3L7RUkByWJczICKsfUaU/XJt5@wofHPHvcsyc8e7FnL/HspVVgzAM)

Comment: Nice you managed to reduce the byte count!

Comment: A different approach with the same byte count:  `Limit[D[#/#2,{x,#3}]/#3!,x->0]&`  (It calculates the *k*th-order coefficient in the Taylor series of the quotient, which will just be the polynomial coefficient.  Note that setting *x* to 0 via `... /.x->0` doesn't work for all polynomials.)

Comment: Unfortunately, `SeriesCoefficient[#/#2,{x,0,#3}]&` is two bytes longer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes, I tried many things myself but they didn't work for all cases...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 81 bytes

Takes input as `(a,p,k)`. The polynomial coefficients are expected from highest to lowest.

```javascript
(a,[c,...p],k)=>a.slice(p.length+k).map((_,n)=>p.map(v=>a[++n]-=v*q,q=a[n]/c))&&q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDbboMwDH3nK/xQVckIGSkrbGLp274iitaIhbaDcq3QJMS3M4et6jbtwec4xz62lXczmD7rTs0lqOo3O@dyJoapjHHOG80KKneG9@Ups6Thpa0Ol6NfUH42DSGvrMJyszwG7FO@X@lADncta6VRlb7PKF2v2zlVHoBSYqMZqAeEULNFCTFlEDsZOUIWt0ryHSL54ljcWsU19GK7WoItwsYl0RZBJBHio9OQn5ziauKfIbH2tMfzunsx2ZEQZRg0DM7mQ1OQOxhxQ1ZXfV1aXtYH4so09VBFCylAQphCAc/SWTDzfbp4frv2LVmNxYQTYTXmROEfG807O9iut4TiVcuv/1QKOu0pDpr@HIDLJzp/Ag)

Comment: What is going on with the &&q at the end? Is it just to return the coefficient you want? `q` stores the intermediate coefficients of the quotient, right?

Comment: @RGS Yes, the last \$q\$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>51 49</s> 48 bytes

Input: `a`, `p`, `k`. The format for the polynomials `a` and `p` is a list of coefficients, in order of highest to lowest degree.

```python
lambda*p,k:numpy.polydiv(*p)[0][~k]
import numpy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLBboMwDIbvPIXFLqEKiECBrlL7FLsxDkwNbdQUoiR047JXZw5dhSZt0toeYgf//r8IJ2qwh65Nx2bzOsr69LarF4oe121/UkOkOjnsxJksVFDGVfl5rDxxUp22MOnj@0FIDi@652sPDGxAtKq3JIiMksISH8It@IEHNUXmhp9rSQyCsPIEstZ7bizwD9W1vLXQCG0s9kaan7k2nGCb@vGhRWtJQy60Y0DBD7c@BVOyKhhLllQUyiWG2J2bemWMWwq5K2NOr0r8m8KckkxK8b1Ycck5m1vZdV1hxU0WNp//X0viLOwmS@os@WQJMwyJ26QZBlakGFeuhvnZVZzG/vq7MHuQwuYZ3Q@ZRoDyg5hpLOHqQcpyvo/7Idn8Du6H5JexfAE)

Comment: Turns out importing numpy gives a really short answer! +1 well played

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 24 bytes

```
f(a,p,k)=polcoeff(a/p,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVDLCsIwEPyV0FMCKXaTPvSg3@A95FCklWKxoQTBr4@7aNVTtcbDzsxOdickrh679OhCaHktnTyJrRv6w9C02K@oD7Vz/ZV7lu6YG7uz52Y/9GNz4d6AFZI9O0WdN9paltB0wlr@aVQgG2NAWeQcISNhMhSSlaSR9YwPk189Cqo7l/AahKneg75dWHyDWrqgp4W0QFAkdIEAlUZck4e8IYfOYO5Vv0dAfISKj/jDX@TxEUV8RGmtCDc)

Comment: I see :p really short submission! Good job +1